# Move Rotated object to specific point

Tags: javascript, linear-algebra

I've an object with the following information

```
const object = {
    x:100,
    y:100,
    width:100,
    height:100,
    angle:45
}
```

Each corner computed by this formula

```
const corner = {
    x: (x - centerX) * Math.cos(rad) - (y - centerY) * Math.sin(rad) + centerX,
    y: (x - centerX) * Math.sin(rad) + (y - centerY) * Math.cos(rad) + centerY
}

const tlPoint = {x: 150, y: 79.28932188134524 }
```

So what i want is the formula to calculate new coordinates if i want to move the object to put the top-left corner on 100px;

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Whats not working? Simply regenerate the corners...

Comment: when the top-left corner is on 100px with 45deg , the real x & y is  {x: 50, y: 120}, so how to calculate these new  values?